# an issue about the python Threading

Tags: python

I have been studying Python recently, and  met some problem when I explore some knowledge about threading.Thread  .  the example code are as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

    #!/usr/bin/env python3.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from threading import Condition, Thread
import time


class ProductAndConsumer(object):
    """ test the threading.Condition function in python.  the class will simulates a simple
        Product and Consumer process mode

        Attribute:
            __con :  a instance of threading.Condtion
            —products:  the list contains all products which is not consumed

    """

    __con = Condition()
    _products = []

    def product(self, name):
        """ the Producter that will product a product.

        Args:
            @name the name of the producted product




        there are no return value

        """
        if self.__con.acquire():
            self._products.append('product-'+name)
            print "product a product, the product's name is:" + name
            self.__con.notify()

    def consume(self):
        """ get a product from product container(products) and consume it( remove it from products）
        """
        if self.__con.acquire():
            flag = True
            while flag:
                if len(self._products) <= 0:
                    print 'there are no products, wait......'
                else:
                    print "consume a product,product'name is:"+self._product.pop()   # consume a product
                self.__con.wait()

    pc = ProductAndConsumer()

    Thread(target=pc.consume).start()
    time.sleep(5)
    Thread(target=pc.product, args=('xiaoxin',)).start()
```

the print result are as following:

```
  there are no products, wait......
 product a product, the product's name is:xiaoxin
```

why the following string not been printed?

```
  "consume a product,product'name is:product-xiaoxin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the bug `self.__product.pop()` to `self.__products.pop()` in your consume thread function.

You need to release the **Condition** after notifying in your producer thread.  Add the line `self.__con.release()` after the notify.